# how to extract information and put it in the name file

Tags: command-line, shell-script

I have several folders with many html files and I need to batch search for specific information within these html and insert this information in the file name as a suffix

The information is: DATE | HOUR in the format below

```
<p> 10 de junho de 2010 | 21h30 </p>
```

The information structure is the same in all html files, but the day, month, year and time are different in all files.

I am not able to indicate a regular expression for this and neither use grep and awk properly.

Any suggestions on how to extract this information and put it in the name file as a suffix?

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question and clarify which OS you are running.

Answer (score 0):

In a `bash` environment (on Linux or CygWin under Windows), you can use:

```
$ LANG=es_ES-UTF-8 ; find . -type f -iname '*.html' | while IFS= read -r filename ; do ts=`stat --format=%Y "$filename"` ; suffix=`date --date=@$ts +%d\ de\ %B\ de\ %Y\ \|\ %Hh%M` ; mv "$filename" "$filename.$suffix" ; done
```

Assuming that:

- you want to use Spanish language
- you want to rename only files (not directories nor symlinks) with extension `.html`
- you want to put as suffix date/time of data modification (not file creation, nor last access, nor last status change)